# How to call an export function from another export function in same file?

Tags: node.js

I have a file which contain 2 functions like below.

```
module.exports.ABC = (reqData, callback) => {
this.DEF(req);
}
module.exports.DEF = (reqData, callback) => {
}
```

How can I call DEF function  inside ABC function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call other by doing this

```
module.exports.ABC = (reqData, callback) => {
  module.exports.DEF(req);
}
module.exports.DEF = (reqData, callback) => {
}
```